# Energy efficiency of muscles and animals as a whole

Tags: muscles, energy-metabolism

When human or animal do some work, they use energy from their food. What is known about overall efficiency of this process?

Say a horse is turning a winch and does 10,000 kJ of work. How much more food will it eat to sustain that effort (compared to when it just stands around)?